# Multiline entries in a kickstart file using backslash escapes

Tags: centos, escape-characters, kickstart

Has anyone tried something like

```
network \
  --activate \
  --onboot=yes \
  --bootproto=static \
  --etc. \
  --etc. \
  --etc....
```

In order to make a kickstart file more readable? Do backslash escapes work?

I'm looking at CentOS 7, so latest and greatest, more or less.

Comment: [The documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html#idp32821936) specifically says: "All static networking configuration information must be specified on one line; you cannot wrap lines using a backslash (\) as you can on a command line."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the only places in a kickstart file that you can use line continuations are the `%pre` and `%post` scripts.  That is because whatever you place between `%pre` (or `%post`) and its `%end` is just given as-is to the interpreter (possibly given by `--interpreter`).

Every other line in the kickstart file (apart from `%packages` and `%addon`) is executed line-by-line.

Notes:

- I never used any addons, not sure if you can actually place something meaningful between `%addon` and its `%end` and whether that can have line continuations.
- You can use `\` and then preprocess your file, for example with `sed -z 's/\\\s*\n//'`*

<sub>* (`-z` is specific to GNU `sed`)</sub>

Comment: Well, drat. Too bad anaconda hasn't been improved to the point where it will parse backslash escapes. Thanks for the answer!